# TL431 output wrong

Tags: tl431

The purpose of the circuit below is to get a V_cathode of 2.5V (Vref) when VDC is higher than 10.4V approximately. The problem is that when VDC>10.4V the voltage checked in V_cathode is 1.9V instead of 2.5V.

3V3_UC_PIN comes from a microcontroller pin that "enables" this circuit. It this case, it is always enabled (+3V3).

I tried with a lower R1 (33 ohms) as well but the result is the same.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: That circuit won't do what you expect it to.

Comment: You are running the device open-loop. Read the datasheet to find the correct closed-loop configuration.

Comment: "when VDC is higher than 10.4V approximately" Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: When run open-loop like this, the on-state anode-cathode voltage will always be around 2V. If you just want a 2.5V reference you could connect the top of R2 to the cathode pin, and change the resistor values; to include your 10.4V check, you'd need more circuitry.

Comment: Where is V_cathode going to?  If back to the microcontroller, couldn't you use an analogue input to measure the voltage across the potential divider?

Comment: You are using the TL431 as a comparator. It can’t simultaneously do that and regulate the output voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know from the description what is problem this circuit attempts to solve.

This [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva987a/slva987a.pdf) application report is very comprehensive and presents the following solution to use the TL431 as a comparator with practically rail-to-rail output, without the voltage excursion limits of the TL431 output:

[image]

This short [article](https://www.edn.com/shunt-regulator-monitors-battery-voltage/) presents a different solution with hysteresis (positive feedback):

[image]

The transition voltages are:

\$V_{T+} = 2.5 \times \left( 1 + \frac{R_1}{R_3} \right)\$

\$V_{T–} = 2.5 \times \left( 1 + R_1 \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \times \frac{1}{R_3} \right)\$